# MapReduce word count using C++ transform_reduce() function with a parallel execution policy

Tags: c++, mapreduce, c++17, std

I have a string of words and I would like to count the number of occurrences of each word, and store the results in a map. I want to use std::transform_reduce() in order to take advantage of it's parallel processing option and use it on a much larger dataset.

e.g.

```
std::string text = "apple orange banana apple apple orange";

std::istringstream iss(text);

// Put these words into a vector
// Define a vector (CTAD), use its range constructor and the std::istream_iterator as iterator
std::vector words(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss), {});

// Aim: Use transform_reduce() to populate an unordered_map that maps each word to its word count

std::unordered_map<std::string, int> wordCount;

// Count the occurrences using transform_reduce
std::transform_reduce(
    words.begin(),
    words.end(), 
    // use the unordered_map wordCount somehow?
    // [](){ lambda for reduce to populate the unordered_map wordCount}
    // [](){ lambda for transforming the words vector of data to pairs: e.g. ("apple", 1) }
);
```

How would I achieve this in C++17 or later using transform_reduce()?

Note: chatGPT had a stab at it, but its code didn't compile and I cannot see how to make it work.

Comment: I'm not sure how `transform_reduce` can help here. I wonder if `for(auto& word : words) ++wordCount[word];` isn't still the cleanest way to do it in C++17 & 20.

Comment: *chatGPT had a stab at it, but its code didn't compile*. It can't write any code, it searches in its code collection, shuffles and combines found code pieces and gives a result, that rarely is working if ChatGPT can't find a code exactly matching a question. Nobody used `std::transform_reduce` for counting words in a vector, thus you got a not working code guessed by ChatGPT.

Comment: I wanted it to do the computations in parallel for a much larger dataset, hence the desire to use transform_reduce.

Comment: The question is complete different from the aim "I wanted it to do the computations in parallel for a much larger dataset". At least the input would not be a vector but rather a hash map of word frequencies.

Comment: I was assuming that the definition of MapReduce is a programming model and an associated implementation for processing and generating big data sets with a parallel, distributed algorithm. I thought that was the whole point of it and I assumed transform_reduce() was the same- it does have a version that takes an ExecutionPolicy as the first parameter.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a `std::ranges::subrange` then use a range based for loop.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <iterator>



int main()
{
    using StreamWordIter = std::istream_iterator<std::string>;
    using SubRange       = std::ranges::subrange;

    std::string        text = "apple orange banana apple apple orange";    
    std::istringstream iss(text);

    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> wordCount;
    for (auto const& word: SubRange(StreamWordIter{iss}, StreamWordIter{})) {
        ++wordCount[word];
    }

    for (auto const& [word, count]: wordCount) {
        std::cout << "  Word: " << word << " => " << count << "\n";
    }
}
```